# How do I equip my unlocked equipment

Tags: magicka-2

Progressing along the scenario I've unlocked a series of items. Weapons and staff I can carry right away, but robes?

Where do I find my equipment and can I change it while in a game?

Answer (score 1):

Hover over your name at the bottom of the main menu, then go to equipment.